# Verify self-issued chained cert with Ruby OpenSSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

I'm trying to us ActiveResource to pull from an internal API where we have a self-issued cert chain with 3 certs inside in PEM format. ActiveResource just passes the `ssl_options` to Net::HTTP so that shouldn't be a factor.

I've tried a number of options to get it to work including:

```
store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
store.add_file('foo.com.chained.crt')
self.ssl_options = {
  cert_store:  store,
  verify_depth: 3,
  verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER,
}
```

I've also tried using this method perscribed in the [source](https://github.com/rails/activeresource/blob/411aa5ccfab1ba41adaee165f456b52b9494b849/lib/active_resource/base.rb#L166)

```
 class Person < ActiveResource::Base
    self.site = "https://secure.api.people.com/"

    File.open(pem_file_path, 'rb') do |pem_file|
      self.ssl_options = {
        cert:        OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(pem_file),
        # key:         OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pem_file),
        verify_depth: 3,
        verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER }
    end
  end
```

As well as many permutations of these and other inputs like `key` and setting the `.crt` file as `ca_file`. None work and all give me the following error:

```
ActiveResource::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
```

Except when I use the `key` parameter, which gives me:

```
OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: nested asn1 error
```

I'm really stuck here and this API is severely making me question my understanding of SSL. I would assume to authenticate the server, all you'd need would be the chained cert. I'm confused how the public key fits in and I really don't understand why explicitly creating a local trusted store and referencing that doesn't work.

I'm using `verify_depth: 3` since the chained cert has three signatures, but I've tried without that option and it still doesn't work. The only thing that seems to work is using `VERIFY_NONE`, which is obviously wrong.

**My question is** how should I properly configure OpenSSL in Ruby to use a self-issued, chained certificate in one `.crt` file? And why haven't the method's I've listed above worked?

Comment: I have no idea what your store certificate contains but it should contain the end of the trust chain, i.e. the one certificate which fits at the end of the certificate chain sent by the server. And of course all certificates except the server certificate should be CA certificates, i.e. have the basic constraint CA:true. You also might try to remove the `verify_depth` setting.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the file does contain the certs in proper order and I've tried with and without the verify_depth option.